# Second monitor on 16.04 from AMD RX 460 (pro 16.60)

Tags: multiple-monitors, amd-graphics

Both connected to graphic card. First one is connected via DVI and it works fine. Second is going from HDMI and shows no signal. Here is xrandr output:

```
Screen 0: minimum 320 x 200, current 1920 x 1080, maximum 16384 x 16384
DisplayPort-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
HDMI-A-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DVI-D-0 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 477mm x 268mm
```

Everything works fine on windows.

Comment: I have the exact same issue and am looking for a solution still.  If I find one I'll report back.  Also, do you experience any weird freezing issues with AMDGPU-PRO 16.60?  My system freezes after about 30+ minutes since installing it.

Comment: There was few hangs so I had to do hard reset. Probably because of gpu drivers. Now I am on integrated graphics and the problem seems to be gone.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved this issue by uninstalling the AMDGPU-PRO drivers and installing the ones from this PPA: https://launchpad.net/~paulo-miguel-dias/+archive/ubuntu/mesa/.  I'd assume the default ones that launch with 16.04 would work as well.  Apparently the AMDGPU-PRO drivers have some issue, at least for me, with dual monitors.

One thing I am curious about, did you have the dual monitor setup before installing the AMDGPU-PRO drivers or after?  I added my second monitor after and had this issue.

Comment: There was only one monitor when ubuntu installed. And right after installation there was incredibly low fps so I installed amdgpu-pro and problem was solved. Until I connected the second monitor. Can't check your solution, because I not own it already.

Comment: It's OK.  Was just offering my two cents because I had the same issue and couldn't get it fixed except by removing AMDGPU-PRO.  Seems the other graphics PPA's worked just as well but have none of the weird issues AMDGPU-PRO has.